# MVC page loading view that doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I've just deployed my MVC page to the remote server but for some reason whenever I navigate to this site it tries to load up a page that doesn't exist instead of going to the Home Index view.

So i'm trying to navigate to `http://mysite` for example but instead it is always trying to navigate to:

```
http://mysite/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252F
```

I have deleted the Account folder and related items that were created by default in the solution, however it seems like the project is still trying to use them, and I can't find any settings that would show why. Can someone help?

**EDIT:**

I don't know if it helps, but this is a VS2015, MVC 5 project running on IIS 7.5. The detailed error says:

**Module:** RequestFilteringModule

**Notification:** BeginRequest

**Handler:** ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0

**Error Code:** 0x00000000

**EDIT 2**

I've just found this code in the Startup.Auth.cs file that appears to be directing to the Account/Login page:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check your authentication settings in Web.config. Even if you've removed the associated MVC components, the web app will still be configured to use Forms authentication.

Comment: I've got my web.config using authentication mode ="Windows" and that appears to be the only part of the file I can see that relates to authentication

Comment: Are there any lingering [Authorize] attributes on your controllers or their action methods? With the information provided, there's a number of things that could be lingering that would cause this behavior.

Comment: I've just done a search in my solution and found there was an old AccountController that was still hanging around. I've removed that though and it's still having the same issue. I'm afraid I'm not sure what more details to give that might be helpful, but i've updated the main question with a bit more info

Comment: When you're publishing, what means are you using to do so? When I publish, I use WebDeploy, and if you remove files from your application, you have to explicitly configure the publish to delete removed files on the web server. Otherwise, all it will do is update changes to any files that are relevant on the web server. Does the web app run fine when you try to debug it?

Comment: The url your generating suggest you have `[Authorize]` on your `Login()` method (which creates an endless loop and eventually throws an exception because of the query string limit)

Comment: @JaimeStill I am publishing by right clicking on the project and building up a profile. I've had a look on the server itself and I can't see any of the files that I removed. But yeah I runs absolutely fine when I debug it and run it locally from Visual Studio

Comment: I've just seen in a Startup.Auth.cs file that there is a function directing to Account/Login. Will update the main question with the code

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to remove the Startup.Auth.cs file completely. That middleware registration is what's tripping you up.